# Is this C# syntax possible?

Tags: c#, syntax

In one of C# projects I've worked with I've met following piece of code:

```
var session = new Session
{
    Application = /*!!!*/
    {
        PublicApplicationId = appId
    },
    LastActivityTime = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromTicks(1)
};
```

I met it some time ago, but only now I got my hands on it.

I don't have access to the sources anymore, so don't know what `Session` class was meant.

But I'm wondering how is it possible syntactically?

Why is the `Application` property initialized by just some JSON-like object in braces?

Any Ideas?

addition: /*!!!*/ - I put this comment to mark the strange place. there were nothing there, no "new SomeClass"

UPD: thanks for the answer!
here is a more human-readable description of this feature: https://fuqua.io/blog/2020/12/a-lesser-known-csharp-feature-nested-object-initializers/

Comment: Its called an "object initializer". Look it up and you'll find all the information you need.

Comment: What does `/*!!!*/` mean? Does that mean there is code there? Then it is possible. Did you mean to signal there *is no* code there? Then it is not. You need a least a `new` there to even create an anonymous class.

Comment: @nvoigt, yes there was nothing there :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax without new keyword is called **nested object initializer**, and I can only find the footprint in the [specification](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v8/standard/expressions.md#117153-object-initializers)

> A member initializer that specifies an object initializer after the equals sign is a nested object initializer, i.e., an initialization of an embedded object. Instead of assigning a new value to the field or property, the assignments in the nested object initializer are treated as assignments to members of the field or property. Nested object initializers cannot be applied to properties with a value type, or to read-only fields with a value type.

So the Application prop doesn't get initialized, the code is equivalent to

```
session.Application.PublicApplicationId = appId;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code would initialize an object like this:

```cs
public class Session
{
    public Session()
    {
        this.Application = new Application();
    }

    public Application Application { get; }
    public DateTime LastActivityTime { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    public int PublicApplicationId { get; set; }
}
```

See how the `Application` property isn't settable? It's a read-only property, so you can't assign a new value to it. You must use the existing value set by the constructor. Therefore, the syntax you've observed allows you to use the object initializer pattern to set `Application`'s variables.

For more information, see [Object Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers) in the documentation.

Comment: Did you *try* that? A readonly property can *not* be set in an initializer. It needs a `set;` or at least `init;`. Also, not the absence of any `new` in the OPs question.

Comment: I just tried it and I was surprised that it actually works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IK7RTT

Comment: @nvoigt I've used it many times. [Example of it in action](https://rextester.com/QORVA39985)

Comment: @nvoigt not only that works, it also "works" when you don't initialize the object to start with... leading to perfect NRE at run time (which is extremely hard to spot for first time since you totally going to see that missing `new` in the code while reviewing... )

Comment: hm, yes, it seems so. Super weird. Why was the `init;` invented then?

Comment: @nvoigt 1) a reference type can avoid the `new` keyword, but POCO types will result in error, (note that `LastActivityTime` has setter above) -- 2) `init` fixes setter issue, but also adds additional capabilities like setting default values without specifying all properties in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, there isn't a 'new', so maybe the property `Application` has been `new`.
like this:

```cs
namespace ConsoleAppForTest;

internal class ObjectA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class ObjectB
{
    public ObjectA ObjA { get; set; } = new ObjectA();
    public int Num { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ObjectB b = new ObjectB
        {
            ObjA =
            {
                Name = "MyTest"
            },
            Num = 1
        };

        Console.WriteLine(b.ObjA.Name); // MyTest
        Console.WriteLine(b.Num); // 1
    }
}
```

Just like shingo said before, it do the same thing as `session.Application.PublicApplicationId = appId;`

Comment: The OP has code *without* the `new ObjectA`. That's what they are asking about I guess.